# React scripts not loading on localhost using npm start, but load when opening the index.html in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, webpack

I've been learning react and webpack at the same time to try set up a webapp to learn web development. I've recently started learning react to make some toggle buttons work, but for some reason they don't work when i run npm start and navigate to localhost, but they do work when i double click my html file in my dist folder. There are no error messages, just a few warnings about script sizes.

The buttons load, so I assume my app.js is correct

```
import React from "react";
import ToggleButton from "./togglebutton";

const App = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, React with Webpack!</h1>
        <ToggleButton label="button1" />
        <ToggleButton label="button2" />
        <ToggleButton label="button3" />
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default App;
```

But the buttons have seemingly no functionality. Leading me to believe the issue is in my togglebutton.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ToggleButton = ({ label }) => {
    // Use state to track the current state (On or Off)
    const [isOn, setIsOn] = useState(false);
  
    // Function to handle button click and toggle the state
    const handleClick = () => {
      setIsOn((prevIsOn) => !prevIsOn);
      console.log(`${label} toggled: ${isOn ? 'On' : 'Off'}`);
    };
  
    return (
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {isOn ? 'On' : 'Off'} - {label}
      </button>
    );
};

export default ToggleButton;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

This is my index.html incase its relevant.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>React with Webpack</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="togglebutton.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="index.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This seems to have happened while I have been trying to make the button update synchonrous.